# Ionic / Cordova: Module can't be found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I defined the following app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myApp.controllers'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    }).state('prints', {
        url: '/prints',
        templateUrl: 'templates/photo_prints.html'
    }).state('box', {
        url: '/box',
        templateUrl: 'templates/photo_box.html'
    }).state('book', {
        url: '/book',
        templateUrl: 'templates/photo_book.html'
    }).state('framed', {
        url: '/framed',
        templateUrl: 'templates/photo_framed.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

and this controllers.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'productsFactory', homeController]);

function homeController($scope, productsFactory) {
    $scope.products = [];

    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.products = productsFactory.getProducts();
    }
}
```

I also added both scripts in my index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <!-- Ionic -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- myApp -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/factory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
```

But when I try to run this I get the error:

```
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My Controller can't be found... why? I implemented it exactly like the standard template from cordova or ionic provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your controller's module like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
```

so ...

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
       .controller('HomeController', homeController);

homeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'productsFactory'];

function homeController($scope, productsFactory) {
         $scope.products = [];

     init();

     function init() {
          $scope.products = productsFactory.getProducts();
     }
}
```

This is the [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

UPDATE:

When you create a new Ionic project - let's say sidemenu - you will have one file **controllers.js** where all your controllers are defined.

That's the place where you can defined every single controller your app is going to use:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('sample1Controller', function($scope) {

})

.controller('sample2Controller', function($scope) {

})

.controller('sample3Controller', function($scope) {

});
```

Here, in this sample, I've defined 3 controllers: sample1Controller, sample2Controller, sample3Controller.

This is not the best way to do things, though. Best practice is to have one js file for each controller.
Let's say it's good enough for now.

Your main app **myApp** is defined here:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myApp.controllers'])
```

and I guess it will be attached to some elements in your HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

you're injecting in your app a few modules: `ionic` and your `myApp.controllers`.

**myApp.controllers** is a custom module: the container for your controllers.

You have to define it somewhere. That's the way you would do that:

```
 angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
```

If you want to separate your controllers in each file you can do something like this.
In one file you can put your controller module definition (app.controllers.js):

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []);
```

and in eache file you can have your own controller:

**home.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
   .controller('homeController', function($scope) {

});
```

**contacts.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('contactsController', function($scope) {

});
```

and, of course, you have to include each controller's js file in your **index.html**.

You can have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TC3flS8sOS2ErkqLRUkE?p=preview).

Comment: Maybe this is a better practice but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Create a plunker so we can try to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know what you mean. I created another project using 'ionic start myApp sidemenu' and with it it worked. but after i added another module i had the same problem. it couldnt be found.

Comment: Updated my answer with some explanation. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should only add this line on the top of your controllers.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```